# Is it any way to run two instances of debuggers?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging, flash-builder, adobe-cirrus

I'm working in a project that is a multiplayer game, and it runs on Cirrus.

It would be nice to debug both instances of the running games, not only one, but Flash Builder stops one debug instance as soon as I send a new debug call.

Do you have any ideas if there is a way to have 2 debug instances running at the same time?, maybe oppening 2 Flash Builders.. but it says something about the workspace..

Dont know if what Im asking is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whoops, sorry, immediately after I said this, I found that

> The debugger is an agent that communicates with the application that
>   is running in Flash Player. It connects to your application with a
>   local socket connection. As a result, you might have to disable
>   anti-virus software to use it if your anti-virus software prevents
>   socket communication. The debugger uses this connection to transfer
>   information from the SWF file to the command line so that you can add
>   breakpoints, inspect variables, and do other common debugging tasks.
>   The port through which the debugger connects to your application is
>   7935. You cannot change this port.

But I'll look into the sources, it shouldn't be that difficult to build fdb with a different port set up.

**EDIT:**

OK, it looks like what you have to do is simply run fdb like this:

```
$ ./fdb -p=9090
```

9090 - is just a randomly selected port number, you would need then to right-click your SWF you are debugging and configure it to connect to localhost:9090.

**EDIT2:**

If it doesn't work, then change line 51 in ${SDK}/modules/debugger/src/java/flash/tools/debugger/concrete/DProtocol.java to a different port, and then rebuild the SDK (probably you can build only the debugger project, but just "to make sure"), you'd have yet another version of debugger that will connect on a different port.

Comment: I see, but even if I can change the port manually, what would be the best way to run two instances of the same project?, maybe having two different projects but... I should replicate the same changes in both, I dont know exactly how to proceed to be honest.

Comment: I see... maybe having 2 Flash Builders running the same project.

Comment: Are we talking AIR projects? I know that ADL (AIR debug launcher) can't run multiple instances of the same app. Is this the issue?